# WireGuard. Низкая скорость между клиентами

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn, wireguard

Есть Wireguard сервер Selectel в Москве, Wireguard клиент Hetzner в США и Wireguard клиент просто в Москве. Скорость через iperf3 между Wireguard сервер в Москве -> Wireguard клиент Hetzner в США - 200Мбит/c.
Cкорость через iperf3 между Wireguard сервер в Москве -> Wireguard клиент в Москве - 400Мбит/c.
Проблема: почему-то cкорость Wireguard клиент в Москве -> Wireguard клиент в США - 15Мбит/c.